# How to test a MobX store function asynchronously with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mobx

I've tried a lot of ways to test if the function `addItem` in my MobX store adds an item to the orders that have been fetched, but I think the orders being fetched asynchronously is causing trouble because `orders` stays undefined.

However, I wàs able to test the asynchronous call in my API of the orders being fetched with jest.

*Sidenote: this is my first time using Jest so sorry in advance if I'm doing some stuff that's not the best idea to do*

**orderStore.js**

```
import {observable, action} from 'mobx';

import {orderAPI} from '../lib/api';

class Store {
  constructor(){
    this.fetchOrders();
  }

  @observable orders = []
  @observable state = "pending"

  @action
  fetchOrders = () => {
    this.orders = [];
    this.state = "pending";
    return orderAPI.fetchOrders()
      .then(orders => {
        this.orders = orders;
        this.state = "done";
        console.log(orders);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.state = "error";
      });
  }

  @action
  addItem = (orderId, productId, price) => {
    const order = this.findSpecificOrder(orderId);
    if (order.items.filter(item => item['product-id'] === productId).length === 0) {
      const itemToAdd = Object.assign({
        "product-id": productId,
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit-price": price,
        "total": price
      });
      order.items.push(itemToAdd);
    }else{
      this.createDuplicateItemError(productId);
    }
  }

  @action
  createDuplicateItemError = productId => {
    // this.addItemErrors[productId] = 'This item is already included in the order.';
  }

  @action
  removeItem = (productId, customerId, orderId, posInArray) => {
    const order = this.findSpecificOrder(orderId);
    order.items.splice(posInArray, 1);
  }

  @action
  changeItemQuantity = (productId, customerId, orderId, posInArray, operator) => {
    const order = this.findSpecificOrder(orderId);
    const item = order.items[posInArray];
    if (operator === 'decrement') {
      if (parseInt(item.quantity, 10) === 1) {
        this.removeItem(productId, customerId, orderId, posInArray)
      }else{
        item.quantity --;
      }
    }else{
      item.quantity ++;
    }
    this.changeTotal(item);
  }

  @action
  changeTotal = item => {
    const newTotal = this.calculateTotal(item['unit-price'], item.quantity);
    item.total = newTotal;
  }

  @action
  calculateTotal = (price, amount) => {
    return (price * amount).toFixed(2);
  }

  @action
  findSpecificOrder = orderId => {
    return this.orders.filter(nr => nr.id === orderId)['0'];
  }
}

const orderStore = new Store();

export default orderStore;
```

**app.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../src/App';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';
import orderStore from '../src/stores';
import {Provider} from 'mobx-react';
import {orderAPI} from '../src/lib/api';
import {itemAPI} from '../src/lib/api';

it('can add an item to an order', () => {
  return orderStore.orderStore.fetchOrders()
  .then(() => {
    const orderId = 1;
    const productId = "B102";
    const price = "4.99";
    const order = orderStore.orderStore.findSpecificOrder(orderId);
    orderStore.orderStore.addItem(orderId, productId, price);
    const updatedOrder = orderStore.orderStore.findSpecificOrder(orderId);
    expect(order.length).toBe(updatedOrder.length + 1);
  })
})

it('loads the orders', () => {
  return orderAPI.fetchOrders()
  .then(orders => {
    expect(orders).toBeDefined();
    expect(orders.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
  });
})

it('loads the items', () => {
  return itemAPI.fetchItems()
  .then(items => {
    expect(items.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
  });
})
```

**orderAPI.js**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export default {
  fetchOrders: () => {
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data/orders.json`)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => data.orders)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
}
```

**Test results:**

```
 FAIL  __tests__/App.test.js
  ● can add an item to an order

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

      at Store.<anonymous> (src/stores/orderStore.js:32:18)
      at executeAction (node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.js:867:19)
      at Store.res (node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.js:858:16)
      at _stores2.default.orderStore.fetchOrders.then (__tests__/App.test.js:28:61)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

  ✕ can add an item to an order (10ms)
  ✓ loads the orders (4ms)
  ✓ loads the items (5ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.334s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: the order variable shouldn't be undefined at all, since it is declared as a class property. it is initialized to an empty observable array on instantiation. @kevin try logging orderStore.orders before and after the fetch.

Comment: on second look, you're doing `orderStore.orderStore` why?

Comment: I did orderStore.orderStore because I imported all the stores as "orderStore", that's a mistake from my side, I changed it now to `import orderStore from '../src/stores/orderStore';`. orderStore.orders stays an observable array before and after the fetch, the problem is that jest doesn't wait for the promise to be resolved and to fill up the orders, so that's why order.items is undefined because there is no property items... I need to find how I can make jest wait for the fetch to be resolved, do you have any clue for that?